# SIGFPE - erroneous arithmetic operation - in MPI_Init() in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, slurm

A MPI-parallel Fortran 2008 code is crashing with floating-point exceptions when compiled with the gfortran `-ffpe-trap` flag.

Let's consider the following MWE Fortran program:

```
program mwe
  use mpi_f08
  integer :: ierror
  call MPI_Init(ierror)
  print*,"MPI_Init returned", ierror
end program
```

saved as `mwe.F90`, and accompanied by the CMake configuration

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(mpimwe
    DESCRIPTION "Minimal Working Example for Fortran MPI with SIGFPE safeguards"
    LANGUAGES Fortran)

find_package(MPI COMPONENTS Fortran REQUIRED)
string(APPEND CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS " -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow")

set(exec "mwe")
add_executable(${exec} ${exec}.F90)
target_link_libraries(${exec} ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(${exec} PRIVATE ${MPI_Fortran_MODULE_DIR})
```

Note the `-ffpe-trap` compiler flag. Usage of this flag is recommended by the gfortran man page:

> ```
>   -ffpe-trap=list
>       Specify a list of floating point exception traps to enable.  On most systems, if a
>       floating point exception occurs and the trap for that exception is enabled, a SIGFPE
>       signal will be sent and the program being aborted, producing a core file useful for
>       debugging.
>  [...]
>       The first three exceptions (invalid, zero, and overflow) often indicate serious errors,
>       and unless the program has provisions for dealing with these exceptions, enabling traps
>       for these three exceptions is probably a good idea.
> ```

---

**Machine 1 (personal PC)**: gfortran 10.3.0, Open MPI 4.0.3

Compilation of the code works. Running the code with `mpiexec -np <N>` with N=1..4 works. Running with N>4, or running the code without `mpiexec` does **not** work, but produces this error:

```
$ ./mwe

Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7ff5f4673d21 in ???
#1  0x7ff5f4672ef5 in ???
#2  0x7ff5f44a408f in ???
    at /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
#3  0x7ff5f1f565d3 in ???
#4  0x7ff5f1f0f402 in ???
#5  0x7ff5f1eecf9e in ???
#6  0x7ff5f245c465 in ???
#7  0x7ff5f3f67020 in ???
#8  0x7ff5f3f5a478 in ???
#9  0x7ff5f40e8fcf in ???
#10  0x7ff5f3feae54 in ???
#11  0x7ff5f3e7eef2 in ???
#12  0x7ff5f40212fb in ???
#13  0x7ff5f43af322 in ???
#14  0x7ff5f4353072 in ???
#15  0x7ff5f444aa4b in ???
#16  0x7ff5f4937901 in ???
#17  0x557cd23a41df in ???
#18  0x557cd23a43ce in ???
#19  0x7ff5f4485082 in __libc_start_main
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#20  0x557cd23a410d in ???
#21  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Floating point exception
```

---

**Machine 2 (HPC cluster)**: gfortran 12.2.0, Open MPI 4.1.4, Slurm 22.05.6

Compilation of the code works. Running the code with or without `mpiexec` works for all N. Submitting into a Slurm queue reproduces above SIGFPE:

```
$ ./mwe
 MPI_Init returned           0
$ srun ./mwe
srun: job ... queued and waiting for resources
srun: job ... has been allocated resources

Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x152893b5451f in ???
        at ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
#1  0x152892295723 in ???
#2  0x15289226da4e in ???
#3  0x1528924340c5 in ???
#4  0x152893315992 in ???
#5  0x1528933013d8 in ???
#6  0x15289387d164 in ???
#7  0x15289395e0e6 in ???
#8  0x152893963165 in ???
#9  0x1528939d63bd in ???
#10  0x1528943f98f5 in ???
#11  0x152894225d6c in ???
#12  0x1528945026c7 in ???
#13  0x15289454aa5c in ???
#14  0x4011cc in ???
#15  0x4013aa in ???
#16  0x152893b3bd8f in __libc_start_call_main
        at ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
#17  0x152893b3be3f in __libc_start_main_impl
        at ../csu/libc-start.c:392
#18  0x4010f4 in ???
#19  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
srun: error: worker_node: task 0: Floating point exception
```

In all failing cases, the usage of `-ffpe-trap=overflow` is not a problem, but adding either of `-ffpe-trap=invalid` or `-ffpe-trap=zero` triggers the SIGFPE.

---

**Expected behavior**: I would like to avoid that the very first MPI command, `MPI_Init` would already trigger the floating-point exception safeguards of compilers. Since I have no control over the contents of the MPI infrastructure*, this renders the `-ffpe-trap` flags useless for MPI-parallel code.

*: Just my guess, that the root cause is either somewhere in Open MPI, or that this are multiple bugs that emerged multiple times in different codes (Open MPI, Slurm; the role of the compiler and system libraries is unclear to me).

Comment: Is the OpenMPI compiled for that particular version of GCC (gfortran)? Does the `mpiexec` come from the same version OpenMPI (not just the version number, also the compiler) as the OpenMPI used for compiling?

Comment: Also, what is the exact `mpif90` or equivalent command that the CMake issues? Run your `make` in verbose. E.g., `make VERBOSE=1` https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/make-building-with-cmake-verbose

Comment: Or really just build your test code on the command line using `mpif90` directly and avoid CMake  completely. It seems to be an unnecessary layer that obscures stuff.

Comment: I can positively say that the MWE and Open MPI were compiled with the same gfortran on the cluster. For my PC, I have to rely that the OS packagers (Ubuntu) haven't messed up.

Comment: with `X*` being path specs in the local file system, the call is `/X1/gcc-12.2.0/gcc-12.2.0-X2/bin/gfortran -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow CMakeFiles/mwe.dir/mwe.F90.o -o mwe  -Wl,-rpath,/X1/gcc-12.2.0/openmpi-4.1.4-X3/lib /X1/gcc-12.2.0/openmpi-4.1.4-X3/lib/libmpi_usempif08.so /X1/gcc-12.2.0/openmpi-4.1.4-X3/lib/libmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr.so /X1/gcc-12.2.0/openmpi-4.1.4-X3/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so /X1/gcc-12.2.0/openmpi-4.1.4-X3/lib/libmpi.so`

Comment: This is really peculiar. Worth trying a C language example and a different major version of OpenMPI as well.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in a similar environment. What if you `gdb mwe` on your PC, do you get a more understandable stack trace?

Comment: gdb, good pointer. Weird enough, the stack trace blames `xmlXPathInit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2`, which indeed [divides by zero](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/7846b0a677f8d3ce72486125fa281e92ac9970e8/xpath.c#L505).